# Magento2 static block now being moved via xml

Tags: layout, page-layouts, default.xml, magento2.4

I have a `Magento2.4` based site and I edited the `default.xml` to load static cms block in the footer div and align them next to each other. My issue is one of the static blocks keeps appear outside the container element I am trying to set it to load inside of and I am not sure why.

Here is my `default.xml`

```
<body>
<!-- footer One -->
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_first">
  <arguments>
    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer_first</argument>
  </arguments>
</block>
<move element="footer_first" destination="footer" before="-"/>

<!-- footer second -->
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_second">
  <arguments>
    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer_second</argument>
  </arguments>
</block>
<move element="footer_second" destination="footer" after="footer_first"/>

<!-- footer third -->
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_third">
    <arguments>
      <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer_third</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
<move element="footer_third" destination="footer" after="footer_second"/>

<!-- footer forth -->
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_fourth">
  <arguments>
          <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer_fourth</argument>
  </arguments>
</block>
<move element="footer_fourth" destination="footer" after="footer_third"/>
```

However, what's happening is the `footer_fourth` is loading outside of the `<div class="footer">` div while all the others are loading inside of it?

Here is the code from a view source of the page when I go to it in a browser

```
  <footer class="page-footer"><div class="footer content"><div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
  <h2>Sign up &amp; Save 20%</h2>
  <div class="block newsletter">
      <div class="title"><strong>Newsletter</strong></div>
      <div class="content">
        <form class="form subscribe" novalidate="novalidate" action="http://******.com/newsletter/subscriber/new/" method="post" id="newsletter-validate-detail">
        <div class="field newsletter">
            <div class="control">
                <label for="newsletter">
                    <span class="label">
                        Sign Up for Our Newsletter:                        </span>
                    <input name="email" type="email" id="newsletter" placeholder="Enter your email address" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}">
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <button class="action subscribe primary" title="Subscribe" type="submit" aria-label="Subscribe">
                <span>Subscribe</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

```
<h2>About Us</h2>
<p>place holder text here.</p>
 </div><div class="col-sm-3 text-center">

     <h2>More on Us</h2>
     <ul>
           <li><a href="#" aria-label="About Us link" title="About us">About us</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" aria-label="Conflict-Free link" title="Conflict-link">Conflict-link Diamonds</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" aria-label="Shipping&amp; Returns Link" title="Shipping &amp; Returns">Shipping &amp; Returns</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" aria-label="Privacy Policy Link" title="Privacy Policy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
           <li><a href="http://****.com//contact" aria-label="Contact Us Link" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
```

```
   </div><div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
     <h2>Help &amp; Faqs</h2>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#" title="My Account">My account</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Order History">Order history</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Track My Order">Track my order</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#" title="FAQ's">FAQ's</a></li> 
  </ul>
</div>
</div><div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
<h2>Follow us!</h2>
<ul>
    <li class="in">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="fb">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="yu">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="tw">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="pt">&nbsp;</li>
```

Comment: Please format the code in your question correctly....

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this?

```
<referenceContainer name="footer">
    <!-- footer One -->
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_first">
      <arguments>
        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer_first</argument>
      </arguments>
    </block>

    <!-- footer second -->
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_second">
      <arguments>
        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer_second</argument>
      </arguments>
    </block>

    <!-- footer third -->
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_third">
        <arguments>
          <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer_third</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>

    <!-- footer forth -->
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_fourth">
      <arguments>
          <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer_fourth</argument>
      </arguments>
    </block>

</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: that did not work. I ran upgrade compile and delploy after I edited my default.xml to match what you had.

Comment: You have to clear the layout and full_page cache